# How to add a class to the outermost div tag of my popup modal?

Tags: arrays, join, onclick, addition, queryselector

I have created a modal with a parent id of "abandon-cart-message" . The two ways I want someone to dismiss the popup is clicking outside the modal, and clicking the "x" on the top right of the modal. I created an array of those two selectors, and on click i want to add a class of "hidden". However it's not adding the class and I can't understand WHY!

```
        //popup dismissal
        const dismissSelectors = ["#abandon-cart-message .evg-overlay", "#abandon-cart-message .evg-btn-dismissal"];
        Evergage.cashDom(dismissSelectors.join(",")).on("click", () => {
            console.log("I HAVE BEEN CLICKED.");
            const dismissPopup = document.querySelector("#abandon-cart-message");
            dismissPopup.classList.add("hidden");
        });
    }
```

On click, i tried to add class "hidden" on the parent ID of my modal but it is not showing up.